# USB MIDI keyboard (Oxygen 61) now not appearing in QJackCtl

Tags: usb, alsa, jack, midi

I've had a USB Oxygen61 MIDI keyboard for awhile now, and it has worked fine in the past (maybe a month ago, last I tried).  But now when I plug it in, it no longer shows up in aconnect -l, and I can't see it as an ALSA MIDI device in Jack.

It powers up and dmesg reports this:

```
usb 11-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ohci-pci
```

I can see it listed in lsusb like this:

```
Bus 009 Device 003: ID 0763:2028 Midiman
```

Output of amidi -l:

```
 3 [O61            ]: USB-Audio - Oxygen 61
                      M-Audio Oxygen 61 at usb-0000:00:13.0-1, full speed
```

Where should I start to troubleshoot why this device is not listed in qjackctl as an ALSA device?

Comment: Does it show up in the output of `amidi -l` and `cat /proc/asound/cards`? What is the difference between "now" and previously?

Comment: Adding amidi -l outputs, modifying the question

Comment: Does `snd-seq-midi` show up in the output of `lsmod`? If not, does `modprobe snd-seq-midi` help?

Comment: There we go.  After running modprobe snd-seq-midi, now I can see Oxygen-61 listed in aconnect -l output.

Strange that this module was not loading anymore.

Comment: Apparently, your distribution (whatever it is) broke module loading with some update. File a bug.